# How to request permission to open camera hardware

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I trying to develop an App that uses the Camera hardware in Android. While coding the following line

```
this.mCameraManager.openCamera(cameraIds[0], new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {...}
```

I was asked to explicitly check if the permission is available. when i added the permission check, Android added the following lines

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
```

and I override the follwoing method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

now, i do not know what to write inside the if-statement and the "onRequestPermissionsResult" mentioned above. your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Here go read this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html next time google it first

Answer (score 1):

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

You have to show android permission dialog to users, after that you can catch users motions in onRequestPermissionsResult.

I think that you should look this website : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                   // Open Camera
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// The permission required by the application to work properly
    protected static final String[] requiredPermissions;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 0;

    static {
        List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ));
        requiredPermissions = perms.toArray(new String[perms.size()]);
    }
```

Call verifyPermissions() method in onCreate():

```
private void verifyPermissions() {
        if (!hasAllPermissions()) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    requiredPermissions,
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST
            );
        }
    }

    private boolean hasAllPermissions() {
        // Check if we have all required permissions.
        for (String perm : requiredPermissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (!hasAllPermissions()) {
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```